# Appending the content of one cell to another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'd like to automatically create the content of a cell, based on the value of another cell.

For instance:

Cell content: 1337
Cell content 2, automatically created: http://www.superuser.com/1337

Which means, URL needs to be added. It can be retrieved from another cell, not that important, as long as it gets automatically created. Otherwise I can just type it in myself.

Why: for work, I am creating a Google Form, which gets a value.  The '1337'. In the answer sheet afterwards, it should be listed as the 'http://www.superuser.com/1337'.

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation `&` and the [`hyperlink`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en) command:

```
=hyperlink("http://superuser.com/questions/"&A1)
```

This appends the content of A1 (e.g., the number 1337) to the given string.

If you don't want the string to be a URL (i.e., clickable),  use simply

```
="http://superuser.com/questions/"&A1
```